# How do I rewrite this using a factory function instead?

Tags: javascript

```
function Person(){
  this.age = 0;
}

var p = new Person();
```

We can compose factories to build arbitrarily complex objects that [don’t require us to mess around with new or this](https://www.sitepoint.com/factory-functions-javascript/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factory functions are just functions which return an object. They may or may not takes some parameters to modify the object they generate. So this could be rewritten like this:

```
function createPerson() {
  return {
    age: 0
  };
}
```

This isn't *exactly* the same because it does not have the `Person` prototype but if you aren't going to use `Person.prototype` then they're functionally the same.

The very first code snippet on the page you linked to shows almost exactly this but with a "jelly" object.